# What does "find out" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

At a university:

> A: 'Oh no! We had to hand a project in!'
>
> B: 'You could make up an excuse...'
>
> A: 'He won't fall for that, and wait until my dad **finds out**! He'll be furious!'
>
> B: 'Don't worry, we'll work something out!'

Why did A say "...my dad finds out"? I don't really understand what it means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. I had never thought much about this before.

The word *find* can mean **to reveal or discover**. It's generally used as a transitive verb:

> I think the scientists will **find** no correlation in the data.
>
> My grandmother **found** an old purse in her attic.
>
> The explorers walked along the coast, hoping to **find** a good harbor.

However, the word *out* can be added when we are talking about discovering a **fact**, or some **information**. In my three example sentences, this can easily be applied to the first one, like this:

> Is there any correlation in the data? That's what the scientists want to find **out**.

or:

> The scientists want to find **out** if there is any correlation in the data.

That's why we can say:

> My parents found **out** I came home late last night.

(they discovered the *fact*). However, we would NOT say:

> The explorers hoped to find <strike>**out**</strike> a good harbor.

or:

> My grandmother found <strike>**out**</strike> an old purse in her attic.

Yet we COULD say:

> My grandmother found **out** she had an old purse in her attic.

because that is talking about a *fact*, not a *purse*. Similarly:

> The explorers found **out** there was no good harbor on the coastline.

is okay, but when we change this from talking about a *fact* to talking about a *harbor*, we say:

> The explorers found no good harbor on the coastline.

with no "out" used.

Comment: Thank you, they make me sure that how to use find out with your examples.

Answer (score 1):

By **find out** A means that his dad will **discover** the truth that A has not given in his project.  Another way of saying this is that A is saying that his dad will **learn** that A has not given in his project.

Comment: Does it mean his father will get to know that he hasn't given it in?  
I'm not clear about discover concept..